problem making a passthrough query via oracle in Access
I am having a problem with making an Access passthrough query in the following code which uses Oracle as the database:
Sub doit()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
    c = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12102_64};dbq=<<location>>;PUID=<<myuid>>;PWD=<<mypwd>>;"
    qdf.Connect = c


    qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL"

    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

    Set rs = qdf.openRecordSet
End Sub

The error message I get is Invalid connection string in pass-through query.
I use this connection string successfully when using ADODB.connection; however, it fails in this instance.

In DAO, when using an ODBC connection, you should prefix it with ODBC;
Adjust your code accordingly:
 c = "ODBC;Driver={Oracle in OraClient12102_64};dbq=<<location>>;PUID=<<myuid>>;PWD=<<mypwd>>;"


Thank you. The connection works, however now a new error just appeard. When i try to open the recordset I get the error message: Reserved Error (-7778) there is no message for this error.

I'm not sure about that, it's possibly an issue with the query. SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL isn't the most sensible query, you'd probably want to use some function when using SYS.DUAL and not select columns from it.

I did some research and found out that the solution to this issue is to not use the connection string as mentioned above. The solution is to have the connection string refer to a file DSN, but the file DSN needs to refer back to either an entry in either the system DSN or user DSN tabs. Make a file with the DSN extension like this example:

choose a path and make a text file with the .DSN, for example SAMP_FILE.DSN.
Open in some text editor and enter in this format:

[ODBC]
DSN=<<existing system or user DSN>>
UID=<<userid>>
PWD=<<password>>


Save and close.
In the VBA code make your example:

Sub doit()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set dc = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.Connect = "ODBC;"File Name=<<fulle path to SAMP_FILE.DSN as mentioned above>>;"
    qdf.ODBCTimeout = 15520
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT EXAMPLE_COL FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE where rownum<100"
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
    Set rs = qdf.openRecordSet
    While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("EXAMPLE_COL").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub

It works very nicely
